# How to fix UserPrincipal returning empty string from API call

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .net-core 2.2 application running on a windows server 2012, using angular as the front end SPA. In a windows domain, I have integrated windows authentication running, on the IIS server, I have the site running with Windows Auth as well, the main problem seems to be the service account running the AppPool, IF i run the site with my AD credentials, the site returns the user name and it displays in the angular front end correct, with a

#### Welcome, John Smith

when I run the AppPool with a service account that was created by our security team, the site returns the username as

> " "

empty string.  i confirmed that the service account that runs the app pool does indeed have access to read into Active Directory,  I am at a loss at this point on what else could be wrong.

1. I've used my AD account to run the AppPool and the site runs fine. (this works)
2. I've run the AppPool with the service account and the site does not return the UserPrincipal properly. (broken)
3. I've confirmed the service account can read into Active Directory by running AD users and groups as the service account ( this works)

API Controller:

````
```


#region Get the logged in user
        [HttpGet("api/getLoggedInUserObject")] 
        public async Task<ActionResult> CheckForLoggedInUser()
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await userResolverSerivce.GetUserObject();

                return Ok(user);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Write(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                throw new Exception("User is not logged in");

            }

        }
        #endregion

```
````

User Prinicipal repo

````
```

    public class UserResolver : IUserResolver
        {


            private AuthorizedGroups AuthorizedGroups { get; set; }
            private User _user { get; set; }


            public UserResolver(IOptions<AuthorizedGroups> authorizedGroups, User user)
            {
                AuthorizedGroups = authorizedGroups.Value;
                _user = user;

            }


            public Task<User> GetUserObject()
            {

                _user.FirstName = UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName;
                _user.LastName = UserPrincipal.Current.Surname;
                _user.FullName = $"{_user.FirstName} {_user.LastName}";
                _user.AuthorizedRoles = GetAuthorizedRoles();


                return Task.FromResult(_user);

            }

```
````

Angular HTML:

````
```

    <div>
      <nav class="navbar-dark nav-bar-large bg-dark fixed-top">
        <span class="pull-right userHighlight">Welcome, {{data.userData.fullName}}</span>
        <div class="container" id="navbarNav">

          <img class="image-center" src="../../assets/img/logo_sm.png" />

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

```
````

Angular TS:

````
```

    import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
    import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
    import { User } from '../models/user';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-main-container',
      templateUrl: './main-container.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./main-container.component.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    export class MainContainerComponent implements OnInit {

      private data: any;
      private user: User[];

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.data = this.route.snapshot.data;
        console.log(this.route.snapshot.data);
      }



    }

```
````

The expected output should return the username, under the service account and not an empty string,  I've been scratching my head on why one service account works but not another.  there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is you want to get the identity of the caller and you are assuming that as you are using windows authentication, you should get it.

But .Net core APIs do not support impersonation.  The work around is either to use below code for getting user name

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2#impersonation

Below code may help you:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    try
    {
        var user = (WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity;

        await context.Response
            .WriteAsync($"User: {user.Name}\tState: {user.ImpersonationLevel}\n");

        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, () =>
        {
            var impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            var message =
                $"User: {impersonatedUser.Name}\t" +
                $"State: {impersonatedUser.ImpersonationLevel}";

            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            context.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(e.ToString());
    }
});
```

Comment: I came across this answer before in research, i'm not using impersonation, that's a different issue, i'm talking about the Service account that runs the IIS site is returning an empty string from the UserPrincipal

Comment: Thread static properties are ignored in .Net Core because of Dependency Injection I believe.